# sqoop 1.99.5 installation error - not able to access JDBC connector for mysql 5.6 ( hadoop 2.4.1 cluster running on Ubuntu nodes)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, jdbc, sqoop

Installed sqoop server on one of the slave node (hadoop 2.4.1 cluster running on all ubunutu 14 nodes) , 
*sqoop2-tool verify* returns following error, (also tried placing  mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar into /usr/lib/sqoop/server/lib , /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/ (created this folder) and /var/lib/sqoop  , nothing works )

```
sqoop2-tool verify
Sqoop home directory: /usr/lib/sqoop
Setting SQOOP_HTTP_PORT:     12000
Setting SQOOP_ADMIN_PORT:     12001
Using   CATALINA_OPTS:       
Adding to CATALINA_OPTS:    -Dsqoop.http.port=12000 -Dsqoop.admin.port=12001
Mar 14, 2015 11:02:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/lib/sqoop/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Sqoop tool executor:
    Version: 1.99.5
    Revision: 9665c01f674d69d41a6fcfffb2c0b94590f70f59
    Compiled on Wed Feb 18 09:42:27 PST 2015 by vbasavaraj
Running tool: class org.apache.sqoop.tools.tool.VerifyTool
2015-03-14 23:02:54,477 INFO  [main] core.SqoopServer (SqoopServer.java:initialize(51)) - Booting up Sqoop server
2015-03-14 23:02:54,493 INFO  [main] core.PropertiesConfigurationProvider (PropertiesConfigurationProvider.java:initialize(96)) - Starting config file poller thread
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[WARN, file].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category root set to WARN
log4j: Parsing appender named "file".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "file".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} [%l] %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "file".
log4j: Setting property [file] to [@LOGDIR@/sqoop.log].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [5].
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [25MB].
log4j: setFile called: @LOGDIR@/sqoop.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "file" options.
log4j: Parsing for [org.apache.sqoop] with value=[DEBUG].
log4j: Level token is [DEBUG].
log4j: Category org.apache.sqoop set to DEBUG
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.apache.sqoop=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [org.apache.derby] with value=[INFO].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category org.apache.derby set to INFO
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.apache.derby=[null]
log4j: Finished configuring.
log4j: Could not find root logger information. Is this OK?
log4j: Parsing for [default] with value=[INFO,defaultAppender].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category default set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "defaultAppender".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "defaultAppender".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d %-5p %c: %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "defaultAppender".
log4j: Setting property [file] to [@LOGDIR@/default.audit].
log4j: setFile called: @LOGDIR@/default.audit, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "defaultAppender" options.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.default=[null]
log4j: Finished configuring.
Exception in thread "PurgeThread" org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException: JDBCREPO_0009:Failed to finalize transaction
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.close(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:115)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepository.doWithConnection(JdbcRepository.java:109)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepository.doWithConnection(JdbcRepository.java:61)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepository.purgeSubmissions(JdbcRepository.java:589)
    at org.apache.sqoop.driver.JobManager$PurgeThread.run(JobManager.java:648)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No current connection.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.noCurrentConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.checkIfClosed(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.setupContextStack(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.commit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:334)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:334)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:211)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.close(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:112)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No current connection.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
Verification was successful.
Tool class org.apache.sqoop.tools.tool.VerifyTool has finished correctly.
hduser@slave:/usr/lib/sqoop/bin$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.4.1
Subversion http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1604318
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-06-21T05:43Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum bb7ac0a3c73dc131f4844b873c74b630
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.4.1.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the derby repository actually. In fact, this exception is probably not a problem. The message `Verification was successful.` means that the tool finished correctly. Try starting Sqoop2 via `bin/sqoop.sh server start` and connecting a client to it via `bin/sqoop.sh client`.

Follow up with the community at [user@sqoop.apache.org](http://mailto:user@sqoop.apache.org).